# Display the content of the clicked item in a modal popUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm using React to create an App where i can see the flags and various infos about every country. I'm using an API to fetch the data and i've already mapped them all with a grid. That's my code so far:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor (props){
    super (props);
    this.state={
      countries : [],
      info: ""

    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data;
      console.log(data);

      this.setState({
        countries : data

      })

this.showInfo = this.showInfo.bind(this)

    })

  }

  showInfo (e) {
   console.log(e.target.key);


  }


  render() {


    return (
      <div className="container">
      {this.state.countries.map(country=>

        <Country name={country.name}
                 key={country.name} 
                 population ={country.population} 
                 region={country.region}
                 capital={country.capital}
                 flag={country.flag}
                 showInfo={this.showInfo}
                 />

      )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is my Country-item component:

```
const Country = ({name, population, region, capital, flag, showInfo})=>{
    return (
        <div onClick={showInfo} className="country-item">

           <div className="img">
               <img src={flag}/>
               </div> 
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>population: {population}</p>
            <p>Region: {region}</p>
            <p>Capital: {capital}</p>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Country
```

So far for now i have something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3du6.png)

Now i would like to click on each country box item and display that clicked data inside a modal popUp. If i create a modal and i will map it, of course on click i will have all of them displayed in once. how can i pass the props of that box i clicked on the modal component? i created a function trying to capture for example the key props, but i didn't suceed. What's the best strategy? thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an onClick handler to each country. When it's clicked, save the country name to the state of the containing component. Render the modal with content only from the country clicked:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor (props){
    super (props);
    this.state={
      countries : [],
      info: "",
      clicked: ''
    }

    this.countryClickHandler = e => {
      this.setState({clicked: country.name}, () => {
        window.addEventListener('click', this.closeCountryPopup)
      })
    }
    this.closeCountryPopup = e => {
      this.setState({clicked: ''}, () => {
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.closeCountryPopup)
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        countries : res.data
      })
    })
  }

  renderPopup() {
    // if the clicked flag is falsy, null, or an empty string, don't render anything
    if(!this.state.clicked || this.state.clicked === null || !this.state.clicked.length) return null

    // otherwise, render the only clicked country by filtering it by matching it with the string in the state
    const clickedCountry = this.state.countries.find(country => country.name === this.state.clicked)
    return (
      <div className="popup_container">
        <Country 
            name={clickedCountry.name}
            key={clickedCountry.name} 
            population ={clickedCountry.population} 
            region={clickedCountry.region}
            capital={clickedCountry.capital}
            flag={clickedCountry.flag}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      {this.state.countries.map(country =>
        <div onClick={this.countryClickHandler}>
          <Country 
            name={country.name}
            key={country.name} 
            population ={country.population} 
            region={country.region}
            capital={country.capital}
            flag={country.flag}
          />
       </div>

      )}
      { this.renderPopup() }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component should maintain the state of which country should be displayed in a modal. More specifically `App` component will save in it's `state` if a modal should be displayed and which country to be displayed in the modal.

The `showInfo` prop that you pass to the `Country` component, should notify `App` component when a country is clicked.

I have created a *representative* [example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/harihar/pen/bGNRyQr).

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
            super();
            this.state = {
              showModal: false,
              selectedCountry: {},
              countries: [
                  {name: "Germany", continent: "Europe"},
                  {name: "South Korea", continent: "Asia"},
                  {name: "New Zealnd", continent: "Australia"}
              ]
        };
    }

    handleCloseModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            showModal: false
        });
    }

    showInfo = (name) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedCountry: this.state.countries.find(it => it.name===name),
            showModal: true
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.countries.map((country) => <Country 
                        name={country.name} 
                        continent={country.continent} 
                        showInfo={this.showInfo}
                      />
                    )
                }
                <ReactModal 
                    isOpen={this.state.showModal}
                    contentLabel={this.state.selectedCountry.name}
                >
                    <div className="modal">
                        <div>{this.state.selectedCountry.name}</div>  
                        <div>{this.state.selectedCountry.continent}</div>  
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
                </ReactModal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Country = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="country" onClick={() => props.showInfo(props.name)}>
            <div>{props.name}</div>
            <span>-</span>
            <div>{props.continent}</div>  
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers guys, both were really helpful. My only problem now is that every time i clicked on an item, i geto on the console log always an element before the click. First click starts with an empty object for example. Do you think is because of componentDidMount? Maybe that example without api works different.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you fully. Where have you put your console.log? Can you reproduce it and share some link showcasing it?

Comment: Also, please don't forget to upvote and accept an answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: ok guy i achieved to make  the modal working and now is displaying the same informations of the initial grid. Now i want to access this array but it seems i can't map it. `` languages: Array(1)
0: {iso639_1: "ca", iso639_2: "cat", name: "Catalan", nativeName: "català"}
length: 1``. If i map it from the Api source, i can access that array inside the object, while if i map from the clicked event they said "languages" is undefined.